# Error mounting fstab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, mount, umount

I have read many questions and answers in this and other forums before asking.
I watched videos on Youtube to learn how to deal with the fstab file too.

So forgive me for bringing back this doubt again.

When I start may computer, soon after I choose Linux in Grub, my screen turns black and Ubuntu does not start. When I push the reset button, I do the same thing again and, this time I receive this message:

**An error occurred while mounting /etc/fstab**

**Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery**

It happens every time. I have to reboot to start Ubuntu 12.04.

My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# Partitions description:
#   /dev/sda1 -> Created by Windows7 with boot informations
#   /dev/sda2 -> Windows 7
#   /dev/sda3 -> Linux
#   /dev/sda4 -> Drivers and some programs
#
#   /dev/sdb2 -> External HD
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# nodev,noexec,nosuid
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=2679ab6c-2da8-48eb-8b7b-5f11833934cc / ext4 relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#Entry for /dev/sda4 :
UUID=29811C914EAB7D93 /media/drivers ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=7A8A5F338A5EEAE1 /media/System\040Reserved ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=749CCF049CCEBFBA /windows ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#Entry for /dev/sdb2          
UUID=01CF9881FC472D80 /media/externalHD ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
UUID=12aed398-6f8b-44e6-abe4-c47fef0b751d none swap sw 0 0  
/dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

Comment: This question is not about programming and should be asked on SuperUser, AskUbuntu, or Unix&Linux

Comment: Where did you get those UUIDs? They don't look very UUID-ish to me.
Run the command `blkid` and see if they match. If they don't, change them accordingly.

Comment: @Duck, thank you for placing the question in the right place.

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas, those were assigned automatically by Ubuntu. I did not change any of those.

Answer (score 0):

something strange happend when I tried to solve the problem:

I rebooted the machine againg and started using Windows 7. I then received a message and decided to try again in Ubuntu. I rebooted the pc.

The boot worked just fine.

I remember I installed MoutManager, but I did not change (I think) anything.

I also tryed to install the program Boot Rapair (I saw a video on Youtube), but the installation failed. I typed the following in this order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair-ubuntu
```

As I said, the installation failed. But now Ubuntu launches.

Now, when I open a Terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

And I see this:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
UUID=2679ab6c-2da8-48eb-8b7b-5f11833934cc / ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro,relatime 0 1  
UUID=29811C914EAB7D93 /media/drivers ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
UUID=7A8A5F338A5EEAE1 /media/System\040Reserved ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
UUID=749CCF049CCEBFBA /windows ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
UUID=01CF9881FC472D80 /media/externalHD ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0  
UUID=12aed398-6f8b-44e6-abe4-c47fef0b751d none swap sw 0 0  
/dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

As you can see, **this has none of my comments!!!** And **there are other differences!!!**

The word **defaults** was not in the second line and **relatime was the first option,** not the last.

Does Ubuntu have any way of re-writing that file?